# Javascript misbehaves intermittently with audio files

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have a script that allows me to click on a div to start an audio track at a given offset (thus acting as a cue).  I have several of these divs in a page.  In certain circumstances, they will only play if played in order.  In other circumstances, the offset is misinterpreted.  For example, when I have this div:

```
    <script>
    var status = 'S' ;
    function pausecomp(ms) {
        ms += new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date() < ms){}
    }

    function play_it( aud_id ) {
        if ( status == 'S' ) {
            var offset = $("#"+aud_id+"_offset")[0].value ;
            if ( offset > $("#" + aud_id )[0].duration ) { alert ( "offset beyond end of track" ); return; }
            $("#" + aud_id)[0].currentTime = offset ;
            $("#" + aud_id)[0].volume = 1 ;
            $("#" + aud_id)[0].play() ;
            status = 'P' ;
            $("#"+aud_id+"_div").css('backgroundColor', 'cyan') ;
        } else if ( status == 'P' ) {
            $("#"+aud_id+"_div").css('backgroundColor', 'green') ;
            status = 'F' ;
            fadeout( aud_id ) ;
            stop( aud_id );
            status = 'S' ;
        } else if ( status == 'F' ) {
            stop( aud_id ) ;
            status = 'S' ;
        }
    }

    function fadeout(aud_id) {
    // reduce the volume by .01 every 100 ms
        var volume = $("#" + aud_id)[0].volume ;
        var stop = 100 ;
        if ( volume > 0 ) {
            stop = Math.floor( 100*volume ) ;
        }
        for ( var i = 1 ; i < stop ; i++ ) {
            reduceVol($("#" + aud_id)[0]);
            pausecomp(60) ;
        }
        $("#" + aud_id)[0].volume = 0 ;
    }

    function reduceVol(audio_obj) {
        var volume = audio_obj.volume ;
        volume = volume - 0.01 ;
        if ( volume >= 0 ) {
            audio_obj.volume = volume ;
        }
    }

    function stop(aud_id) {
        $("#" + aud_id)[0].pause() ;
    }
    </script>   

<div style='display:inline-block; width:300px;'>
<audio id="my_audio_3">
    <source src="Artists\The Black Keys\El Camino\01.Lonely Boy.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<input type='hidden' id='my_audio_3_offset' value='185.5' />
<div id='my_audio_3_div' style='background-color:lightblue; width:200px; height:100px; border:1px solid black; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;' onclick="play_it('my_audio_3')">Artists\The Black Keys\El Camino\01.Lonely Boy.    
</div>
<button type="button" style='width:200px;' onclick="stop('my_audio_3')">Stop</button>
</div>
```

In a file by itself, the offset works correctly.  If I have it together with a bunch of similar divs, it doesn't play at all.  In other combinations, (seems like it has to do with certain files, but I haven't been able to narrow down a cause among them), some play properly whenever clicked, some only play if the file before it was played first.

Comment: you need to make sure the segment of audio you wish to play isLoaded before you play() it. the _preload_ attrib might help.

Comment: The preload attrib did nothing for the one specific playback issue.  What I did find interesting is that if i display the controls for all of the tracks, they are all muted except the first six.  Once I play and stop one track, it's display changes to muted (expected) but the next muted track in the page is unmuted.  Is there a limit to how many audio tracks can be simultaneously loaded?

Comment: It appears to be browser specific.  Just tested in IE and works as expected.  in Firefox, NONE of the tracks load.